# How to kill a connection in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, connection

I have a homework assignment to build an `http` server using only node native modules.
I am trying to protect the server from overloading, so each request is hashed and stores.
If a certain request reaches a high number, say 500, I call `socket.destroy()`.

Every interval (one minute) I restart the hash-table. Problem is that when I do a socket that was previously dead is now working again. The only thing I do each interval is `requests = {}`, and nothing to do with the connections.

Any ideas why the connection is live again? Is there a better function to use than `destroy()`?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "a certain request reaches a high number, say 500"? 500 requests per second? The URL is too long?

Answer (score 1):

Destroying the socket won't necessarily stop the client from retrying the request with a new socket.

You might instead try responding minimally with just a non-`OK` status code:

```
if (requests[path] >= 500) {
    res.statusCode = 503;
    res.end();
}
```

And, on the [`503` status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.4):

> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server.